# agent.add not working while console.log is

Tags: node.js, promise, dialogflow-es, webhooks, actions-on-google

**I am using the Dialogflow Inline editor to make a call to an API. When I use console.log to log some of the data from the API it works. However, when I use agent.add with the same variable it gives an error.**

I read some other stackoverflows about this issue where people used a promise and resolve call. I have tried to implement this in my code. However, I'm not sure if I've used it in the right way.

This is my code:

```
'use strict';
const axios = require('axios');
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  
  function randomHandler(agent){
    const regio = agent.parameters.regio;
    if (regio != "Alkmaar" && regio != "Schiphol"){
      agent.add(`Deze regio bestaat helaas niet binnen NH nieuws, kies een andere regio of kies voor het nieuws uit heel Noord-Holland`);
    } else {
        return axios.get(`https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=book`)
    .then((result) => {
        
      result.data.map (res => {
        const dataArray = ""; // An array with the results. However we got it
        const words = dataArray.map( entry => entry.word );  // Get just the "word" field from each entry in the dataArray
        const wordsString = words.join(', ');   // Put commas in between each word
        agent.add( `The results are: ${wordsString}`);
      });
      });
    }
  }
  

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('random', randomHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

and this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
    "axios" : "0.20.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that I called the agent.add more than 2 times (which is the maximum). This code works for me:

```js
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios').default;
const app = conversation();

var titels = [];

axios.get(`YOUR-API`)
  .then((result)=> {
    titels.push(result.data.categories[0].news[0].title);
    /* result.data.map(wordObj => {
      titels.push(wordObj.categories.news.title);
    });*/ 
  }); 
  
app.handle('rhymeHandler', conv => {
  console.log(titels[0]);
  conv.add(titels[0]); 
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);    

/* for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  conv.add(words[i]);
  } */
  //console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you suspected - the problem is with Promises.

`rhymingWordHandler()` has an asynchronous operation in it (the web call using axios), but you're not returning a Promise.

Fortunately, `axios.get()` *does* return a Promise. You can tell because you're calling `.then()` on what is returned, and `.then()` *also* returns a Promise and so forth. I like to this of this as a "Promise-chain". Changing this to return a Promise is relatively simple:

```
return axios.get(`https://api.datamuse.com/words?rel_rhy=${word}`)
  .then( /* and so forth */ )
```

However, this isn't quite enough with your code. You don't need to create a Promise inside the `.then()` function, and doing so only confuses things.

Remember that Intent names are case sensitive - you need to use the exact same capitalization in both the name that you have in the UI as well as the name you use for `intentMap.set()`. You currently have "Rhymingword" in one place and "RhymingWord" in the other (one W is capitalized, the other isn't).

You also may have a minor problem that you may not be able to call `agent.add(rhyme)` multiple times. Some agents can only handle one or two text responses. Instead, you'll need to build the response string from the array of results.

How to build a string like this depends on your exact content. The easiest (although not grammatically correct) is to just put commas in between them. I often do them in steps, so it might look like this:

```
  const dataArray = // An array with the results. However we got it
  const words = dataArray.map( entry => entry.word );  // Get just the "word" field from each entry in the dataArray
  const wordsString = words.join(', ');   // Put commas in between each word
  agent.add( `The results are: ${wordsString}`. );
```

There are lots of problems with this, and a good solution would handle cases such as:

- What if there are no results?
- Should you use a different phrase before the list when there is just one word?
- What if there are two results?
- You should apply correct grammar/punctuation rules for three or more results.

But this should be a start to making sure you call `agent.add()` just once.

Comment: Hi! Thx for the comment I have changed the code (I've updated it in the question). However, it is still not added to the agent. Looks like it can't add something to the agent when it is done within a function? This is the error I get: No handler for requested intent

Comment: That usually suggests a very different problem, that your handler function isn't even being called. Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the Intent you think should be handled, possibly along with an example of the conversation and what happens when you try it?

Comment: Alright! I have added the images of the intent first one) and the execution (the second one).

Comment: Answer updated. Remember that Intent names are case sensitive.

Comment: Sharp! I have changed it see updated code. However, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Which "same issue" are you having?

Comment: It says: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at axios.get.then

Comment: You redefined `result` as being from `result.data`, so I'm assuming you want to map over `result` and not `result.data`

Comment: Yes that's right! I've changed it now (see updated code) but now get the error: TypeError: result.data.map is not a function

Comment: Oke so I think that might be the API, I have now switched to another API and don't get this error anymore. However, the agent.add is not working while the console.log is.

Comment: Which `agent.add()` isn't working? All of them? (As I noted, you may not be able to call it multiple times, so you'll need to build a string and call it once.)

Comment: Aha! Oke the agent.add within the result.data.map function isn't working. How could you make such a string?

Comment: I don't get any real errors anymore in the console, I do get this warning: FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing.

Comment: And the console log withing the result.data.map is working but the agent.add isnt

Comment: I have removed all agent.add's but the one with the map function. This, unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: Oke, I have changed to nodejs 8 and don't get this warning anymore. Everything looks good now in the console but it still doesn't work!!

Comment: I'm sorry its just a little frustrating

Comment: Trust me, we all understand frustrating. The trick to debugging is to learn what is relevant to your problems and what are different issues. I've updated my answer to illustrate one way to create a combined string with the values. The issue about FIREBASE_CONFIG is irrelevant to what you're doing, and you should stick with a more recent version of Firebase.

Comment: Haha thx. I've tried making the Array but this unfortunately doesn't work. The weird thing is that if I do an agent.add("hi") in the map function this doesn't work either

Comment: an agent.add outside the map function does work however! For example when its in axios.get.then

Comment: Yes. the `agent.add()` inside the `.map()` won't work because you'll be doing it multiple times. This is why you use the map to get an array (which is what `.map()` does) and then turn this into a string (which is what `.join()` does in my example). If it still doesn't work - what is happening?

Comment: Hi, alright. I''l update the code so you can see how it looks now.  I don't exactly get it with the map() so wonder if I'm doing it the right way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222409/discussion-between-emilie-van-eps-and-prisoner).